# How to typeset electrochemical cells

Tags: symbols, chemistry, cell

Electrochemical cells should be typeset

- According to the "Green Book" from IUPAC with vertical bars, dashed vertical bars and double dashed vertical bars. (first picture)
- According to Atkins, Physical Chemistry with vertical bar, three vertical dots and double vertical bar. (second picture)

How do i properly typeset those symbols? The single bar I can directly input from the keyboard like "|". For the double, do i just make two bars like "||" or is there a more suitable symbol?
How do i get (double) dashed vertical bars and three vertical dots? In text mode or math mode?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, lipsum, epstopdf, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}   %symbols e.g. °C
\usepackage{textgreek}  %greek letters in text mode
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all}}

\begin{document}
Cu(s) | CuSO4(aq) || KCl(aq) || ZnSO4(aq) | Zn(s)
\end{document}
```

[image: IUPAC, "Green Book"]
[image: Atkins, Physical Chemistry]

Comment: For the vertical dots you can use `\vdots`. You might want to lower it to match the vertical bar by using `\raisebox{-2pt}{\vdots}`, or possibly compress the dots by importing (e.g.) the `MnSymbol` package. There _is_ a math symbol `\|` for a double vertical bar, which gives bars slightly closer together than `||`, but if you're also doubling the vertical dots or dashes those will probably give something more similar to `||`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know this symbol in LaTeX but you may build it with `\vrule`.

```
\newcommand\dashbar{{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{(}%
    \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
    \lower\dp0\hbox{%
      \kern.2pt\relax
      \vrule height .2\dimen0 depth 0pt\kern-.4pt\relax
      \vrule height .6\dimen0 depth -.4\dimen0\kern-.4pt\relax
      \vrule height \dimen0 depth -.8\dimen0\relax
      \kern.2pt\relax
  }}}

\newcommand\dashbarii{\dashbar\dashbar}
\newcommand\dashbariii{\dashbar\dashbar\dashbar}
```

After this,

```
Cu(s) $|$ CuSO$_4$(aq) \dashbarii\ KCl(aq,sat) \dashbarii\ ZnSO$_4$(aq) $|$ Zn(s)
```

gives
[image]

The code above has a small drawback: the dash bars are narrower than the vertical bar `|`. I modified it to ajust this.

```
\makeatletter
 \newcommand\@dashbar{{%
     \setbox0=\hbox{(}%
     \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
     \lower\dp0\hbox{%
       \kern.2pt\relax
       \vrule height .2\dimen0 depth 0pt\kern-.4pt\relax
       \vrule height .6\dimen0 depth -.4\dimen0\kern-.4pt\relax
       \vrule height \dimen0 depth -.8\dimen0\relax
       \kern.2pt\relax
 }}}
\newcommand\dashbar{\begingroup\setbox0\hbox{$|$}\hbox to\wd0\bgroup\hss\@dashbar\@@dashbar}
\newcommand\@@dashbar{\@ifnextchar\dashbar{\@dashbar\expandafter\@@dashbar\@gobble}{\hss\egroup\endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

Now, everythings lines up!

[image]